# Как создать прокси на отдельный поддомен, если есть задано для всех поддоменов

Tags: linux, nginx, jira, confluence

Мне необходимо поместить confluence на поддомен. Как я понимаю для этого мне надо добавить прокси с порта 80 на порт confluence [инструкция](https://wiki.teamlead.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=101680023). Сам этот домен прикреплен к сайту, на котором динамически можно создавать поддомены( переопределение с поддомена confluence будет учитываться). Как мне создать прокси для одного поддомена, переопределив правило для всех алиасов?

```
server {
listen      100.100.100.100:443;
server_name domain.ru *.domain.ru;
ssl         on;
ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.domain.ru.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.domain.ru.key;
error_log  /var/log/httpd/domains/domain.ru.error.log error;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; ";

location / {
    proxy_pass      https://100.100.100.100:8443;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
        root           /home/admin/web/domain.ru/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/domain.ru.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/domain.ru.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }
}

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/domain.ru/document_errors/;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass      https://100.100.100.100:8443;
}

location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

include /home/admin/conf/web/snginx.domain.ru.conf*;
```

}

Comment: Что-то я не догнал сути проблемы. Просто добавить ещё одну секцию server с server_name confluence.domain.ru да и всё, не?

Comment: Не хочу быть занудой https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network